# MobileIron Apps@Work Error

Tags: ios, mdm, mobileiron

I try to deploy the Apps@Work MobileIron application on iPads. The application installs correctly, I've resigned it with iResign. However when I launch it an error message appears:

> Cannot Open Apps@Work Your device is not configured to access
>   Apps@Work. Contact your administrator to ensure you device is
>   registered and configured with a supported MobileIron server.

Then I redirected to the Mobile @ Work application and this message appears:

> Mobile@Work Erreur de l'application : impossible de communiquer avec
>   l'application. Veuillez contacter le développeur de l'application.
>   L'ID du paquet d'applications est com.*

It seems I've no link between Apps@Work and Mobile@Work, do I need to use a specific certificate or a specific bundle id ? I never change the server url in Apps@Work, do I need ?

Thanks

Comment: This is a very specific question on a solution only available for customers with access to the MobileIron knowledge base. Did you already read the complete tech note information for that? I think the MobileIron support is a better place to submit that question.

Answer (score 0):

The app is probably not getting authorized. If you have access to the console log, look for a line with the text `<Warning>: Debug current auth state: 0, message: (message)`. The (message) part will give more specific information about the failure.

The most likely cause is that the initial attempt to authorize the app failed, which would produce the message `<Warning>: Debug current auth state: 0, message: An unexpected error has occurred, so this app cannot be authorized. Check your device's network connection, check for an updated version of this app, and then return to this app after 5 minutes. For more help, contact your administrator.`